# How to access sub objects from an array?

Tags: powershell

I have the following

```
$roles = 'role1;role2;role3;role4' -split ';'
$members = 'member1,member2;;member3;member4' -split ';'

$i = 0
$array = @(foreach ($role in $roles) {
   [pscustomobject] @{
     Role = $role
     Members = $members[$i++] #-split ','
   }
})
```

`$array` outputs:

```
Role  Members
----  -------
role1 member1,member2
role2
role3 member3
role4 member4
```

testing this: `$array.members`

```
member1,member2

member3
member4
```

i am trying to access members for each role

```
$i=-1;
foreach($role in $array.Role)
{   
    $i++; 
    foreach($member in $role[$i].Members){$member}
}
```

to my understanding, i should get back

[image: members]

instead, i get nothing printed back!

how come?

also, if i want to access objects by name, i have an alternative using hashtable, but for some reason, its not working properly.

```
$roleMembers = @{}

for ($i = 0; $i -lt $roles.Count; $i++) {
  # `Where Length -ne 0` to filter out empty strings
  $roleMembers[$roles[$i]] = $members[($i*2)..($i*2+1)] | Where Length -ne 0
}
```

`$roleMembers` outputs

[image: output]

instead of outputting:

[image: hash]

how come the output is different from `$array`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `foreach` over `$array`, and you can access the individual properties inside the loop:

```bsh
foreach($item in $array){
  foreach($member in $item.Members){
    "$($item.Role): $member"
  }
}
```

which will result in

```
role1: member1,member2
role2: 
role3: member3
role4: member4
```

Comment: what if i want to print role in the outside loop then members, something like: 
foreach($role in $array.Role)
{   
    $role;
    foreach($member in $role.Members){$member}
}

Comment: Sure, you can do whatever you want inside the loop body :)

Comment: so can i wrap it like this: foreach($item in $array){foreach($role in $item.Role) { $role; foreach($member in $role.Members){$member} }}

Comment: Sure, but it won't work - `$item.Role` is just a single string (`"role1"` for example)

Comment: ohhh this is probably because of the limitation that array object cant be accessed by name huh...hmm, i think ill go with your hashtable answer as it seems to suit my needs since i want to access the members by role name, but its not printing the correct output. i posted this as well in my post, but if you want i can open a new thread to address the issue?